# Force setup.py to use my custom compiler

Tags: python, c++, macos, macports

I'm trying to get setup.py to compile c++ code with the macports version of gcc. The problem is the code I am trying to build, doesn't support mac's default clang, which is the default gcc on newer osx versions.

I created a custom `setup.cfg` file

setup.cfg

```
[build_ext] 
compiler=gcc-mp-4.8
```

However when I run `python setup.py build_ext` I get the following error

running build_ext

```
error: don't know how to compile C/C++ code on platform 'posix' with 'gcc-mp-4.8' compiler
```

How can I get setup.py to use my version of gcc `gcc-mp-4.8`?

Currently setup.py defaults to using `/usr/bin/clang`,  when i type `gcc -v` it shows that it is using gcc version 4.8.2

Comment: Have you tried using the absolute path to your gcc-mp-4.8?

Comment: @l'L'l still gives an error , `error: don't know how to compile C/C++ code on platform 'posix' with '/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.8' compiler`

Comment: You could also try setting the macports gcc in your path so it defaults to that version; It seems as if it's still looking at clang.

Comment: @l'L'l the question is how, I added more information above as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `--compiler` option expects "unix", "msvc", "cygwin", "mingw32", "bcpp", or "emx", from my understanding. You can try setting the compiler name by specifying a CC environment variable instead.

Inside `setup.py` try setting `os.environ`:

```
os.environ["CC"] = "gcc-4.8"
os.environ["CXX"] = "gcc-4.8"
```

or just:

```
CC=gcc
```

`g++` would be used like this too;

```
os.environ["CXX"] = "g++-4.7"
```