# Failed to specific gcc version when setup python

Tags: python, c++, gcc

It seems that there're some conflicts on CUDA 9.0 and GCC 6.x, (discussed [here](https://github.com/ComputationalRadiationPhysics/alpaka/issues/426#issuecomment-442380754)). So I decide to use gcc 5.5 to setup python package.

According to the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25595274/5634636, and https://stackoverflow.com/a/16737696/5634636, I tried to run `setup.py` as follow:

```
CC=gcc-5 CXX=g++-5 python setup.py install --user
```

which raise the error (I only paste part of it because it's too long):

> /usr/include/c++/6/tuple: In instantiation of ‘static constexpr bool
>   std::_TC<, _Elements>::_MoveConstructibleTuple() [with
>   _UElements = {std::tuple};

It seems that python is still using g++ 6 (/usr/include/c++/**6**/tuple) library on compiling. How to avoid using g++ 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there are two places where `gcc` is used. One is python setup itself, the other is `nvcc`. The environment variable `CC` and `CXX` only specific the gcc version for python, but it didn't change the gcc version for `nvcc`.

To change the gcc version cuda used by default, do as follows:

```
sudo unlink /usr/local/cuda/bin/gcc
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-5 /usr/local/cuda/bin/gcc
```

There `/usr/bin/gcc-5` can be any path to the gcc you want to use.